# Does numerical optimization depend on computer performance?

Tags: performance, matlab, numerical-methods

This may seem like a silly question to most but I tried to same non-linear least square optimization in matlab on two computers and compared to a baseline result of discretized parameter grid. The calibration was able to beat the baseline on one computer and lost to the baseline on another computer. I have checked my codes many times and they appear to be the same optimization.

I am wondering if anyone can let me know if computer performance affects numerical optimization results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the numerical optimization should *not* depend on the computer performance.
There are, however, a few things to consider:

- If your termination condition depends on the amount of time your optimization has been running, then a slower computer would possibly stop too early, hence giving a different result.
- If you are using very different computers (e.g one windows machine and one mac), or two very different versions of matlab the exact implementation of the optimization routine may be different, which may give slightly different results
- If your routine is using random numbers, check your seed values (and matlab versions, see point above), because different seed values might produce different results.

Comment: While unlikely applicable to this situation since matlab does not use them natively, the amount of precision in `long doubles` can vary across machines, which can lead to different results.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85: All x86 hardware has the same 80bit floating point available, but some compilers may use 64bit `long double`.  This is more likely in x86-64 mode, where the calling conventions specify floating point arguments / return values in SSE registers (supporting only 32/64bit float scalars (or vectors of them)).

Comment: If matlab uses the system math library for exponential / log / trig functions, different systems can have different implementations.